# 503 error only when customer logs in (Magento 1.9.4.0)

Tags: magento-1.9, login, session, cookie

Website works fine until a **customer logs in** and then they are presented with a **503 error** when they browse to any **category or product**. The actual **account page** does appear fine once they are logged in.

Only way to rectify this is to clear the session cookies.
I haven't installed any extensions recently and I'm not sure how long this has been happening.

Nothing in the Apache logs.

In `Configuration > Web > Session Cookie Management` I have tried two sets of configs to no avail:

```
Cookie Life Time: 3600
Cookie Path: /
Cookie Domain : .mydomain.com (The dot prefix is important)
Use HTTP Only : No
Cookie Restriction Mode: No

Cookie Life Time: 3600
Cookie Path: <blank>
Cookie Domain : <blank>
Use HTTP Only : Yes
Cookie Restriction Mode: No
```

Is there anywhere else I need to look/check, I'm at my wits end.

> https://www.myshop.co.uk

Comment: Getting any error in log files?

Comment: I can't see any Exception.log. Logging is enabled in the back-end.

Comment: anything in `/var/report/`? Usually Magento creates a file with the error and trace for each error in that folder

Comment: No. Well nothing dated recently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appeared to be an unknown issue with Mirasvit Full Page Cache extension.
Updated to latest version and the 503 errors were resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time(80%) it will be your PHP error for me it due to php errors, so don't diverted on server issues check your logs or debug your code properly.